# Read Data From AM2302

Tags: c, stm32, sensors

I'm trying to read data from an [AM2302](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital+humidity+and+temperature+sensor+AM2302.pdf) but nothing works fine. I am using an STM32L476RG NUCLEO board and have configured GPIOB port 9 as a communication bus for one-wire communication with the sensor.

I would like to obtain the data into the array I called `uint8_t data[40]`.

The code starts with a initial delay of about 2 seconds, then a sequence of wait until starts in order to read the data line as the protocol says.

Here the datasheet of the sensor [link](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital+humidity+and+temperature+sensor+AM2302.pdf)

I connected the sensor as shown in the datasheet:

```
Vdd - 5V nucleo board
data - port GPIOB 9
GND - not connected
GND - GND nucleo board
```

Here is my broken code.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2021 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio_Init;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);

void UF_GPIO_Conf(void);
void UF_GPIO_ChangeMode(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    uint8_t data[40];
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
  UF_GPIO_Conf();

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      HAL_Delay(2020); //Wait 2.020 seconds

      //Start communication
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, RESET);
      HAL_Delay(30);
      UF_GPIO_ChangeMode(); //Input mode

      while(!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9)));    //Wait until the line goes high

      //Synchronization
      while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9)); //Wait until the sensor pull down the line
      while(!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9))); //Wait until the sensor release the line high
      while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9)); //Wait until the sensor pull down the line

      while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9)); //Wait until the line goes down
      while(!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9))); //Wait until the sensor release the line high

      //Data reading
      for(uint8_t count = 0 ; count < 40 ; count++){

          HAL_Delay(0.035);
          if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9)){
              data[count] = 1;
              while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9)); //Wait until the line goes down
          }else{
              data[count] = 0;
          }
          while(!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9))); //Wait until the sensor release the line high

          while(1);

      }
  }
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void UF_GPIO_Conf(void){
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    //GPIOA PIN 5 (USER LED)
    gpio_Init.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    gpio_Init.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    gpio_Init.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    gpio_Init.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpio_Init);

    //GPIOB PIN 9 (COMMUNICATION LINE)
    gpio_Init.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
    gpio_Init.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
    gpio_Init.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    gpio_Init.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio_Init);

}

void UF_GPIO_ChangeMode(void){

    GPIOB->MODER &= ~(0x3 << (18)); //Clear
    GPIOB->MODER |= (0x0 << (18));  //Set as an input


}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: Is AM2302 a temperature-humidity sensor? If so can update the post with datasheet. Can you please us how you have connected your STM32L476RG board

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena yes is a temperature-humidity sensor. I have updated the post. I connected the sensor directly without any capacitor and I used internal pullup resistors.

Comment: Use ready-made library. Your code definitely will not work. There is nothing to be improved. https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2015/07/hal-library-05-onewire-for-stm32fxxx/ or use Arduino.